# How to scroll bootstrap modal on windows phone

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've got a simple modal instance created by angularJS (v1.2.14) with the latest version of bootstrap  (v3.1.1)

The modal won't scroll on my windows phone, instead the whole page scrolls and the modal is clipped to the window size (see screenshot below).

It works fine of course on my desktop in chrome & IE. Haven't tested it on iOS and Android but I guess it works fine.

I added `.modal { position: absolute; }` to bootstrap.css but it doesn't make any difference.

**EDIT**: It appears to be the same issue as this: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11153

[image: Whole page scrolls, modal doesn't (is cut-off)]

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to add the following css style:

```
@-ms-viewport {
    width: auto;
}

html,body {
    -ms-overflow-style: none !important; 
}
```